# Pass GestureState property down through an ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui

I have an `ObservableObject` that has a member property with the `@GestureState` wrapper. In my View, how do I get access to the `GestureState` property?

I've already tried using dot notation with the `$` binding to try to expose the GestureState but it doesn't like that

My AppState `ObservableObject`:

```swift
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    @GestureState var currentState: LongPressState = .inactive

    public enum LongPressState: String {
        case inactive = "inactive"
        case pressing = "pressing"
        case holding = "holding"
    }
}
```

The implementation of the object in my code:

```swift
@ObservedObject var appState: AppState
.
.
.
let longPress = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: minLongPressDuration)
   .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 5))
   .updating(appState.$currentState) { value, state, transaction in
      switch value {
      case .first(true):
         state = .pressing
      case .second(true, false):
         state = .holding
      default:
         state = .inactive
      }
}
```

I'm actually not getting any buildtime errors in this View but it invalidates the View higher up the hierarchy. If I replace the `@ObservedObject` with a local `@GestureState` property then it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a workaround that works perfectly.

The idea is simple: You have your `currentState` two times.

1. Inside your view as a `GestureState`
2. Inside your `ObservableObject` class as `Published`

This is necessary since `GestureState` can only be declared within a view. The only thing left to do now is to somehow sync them.

Here is one possible solution: (using `onChange(of:)`)

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {

    @Published var currentState: LongPressState = .inactive
    
    enum LongPressState: String { ... }
    ...
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var appState = AppState()
    @GestureState private var currentState: AppState.LongPressState = .inactive

     
    var body: some View {
        SomeView() 
            .gesture(
                 LongPressGesture() 
                     .updating($currentState) { value, state, transaction in
                         ...
                     }
            )
            .onChange(of: currentState) { appState.currentState = $0 } 
    }
}
```

#### Note

I have found that the animation was kind of buggy. Adding an `onEnded` to the gesture fixed it (DragGesture).

```
.onEnded { 
   appState.currentState = .inactive //if you are using DragGesture: .zero (just set to it's initial state again)
}
```