# SwiftUI | DragGestures onEnded never called if canceled by ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following problem.

I have a `View` inside a `ScrollView` that I want to drag.
Now, everything works fine, the dragging occurs and the scrolling as well. But once I try to do both, the `dragOffset` appears to stay, instead of resetting to its initial position.

More so, `onEnded` of the `DragGesture` never happens. How can I stop this from happening and reset the green `Rectangle` to its initial position?

### Visual representation

Dragging or scrolling works just fine.

[image] [image]

But whenever I do both, this happens.

[image]

### Demo Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .offset(x: dragOffset.width)
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                dragOffset = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                dragOffset = .zero
            }
        )
        .animation(.default)
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have bettered this by adding a minimum drag distance to the `DragGesture` like so: 
`DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20)`. That made it better for me, but it's just a half fix since one has to now drag more than 20 in order to active the gesture.

Comment: `DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1)` works as well

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is to use `.updating` with `GestureState` instead. It automatically sets the offset to its initial position, after the gesture got canceled for whatever reason.

That way, we are independent of calling `onEnded` to set it to its initial position which doesn't happen when you cancel the gesture by scrolling.

[image]

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @GestureState private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .offset(x: dragOffset.width)
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture()
            .updating($dragOffset) { value, state, transaction in
                state = value.translation
            }
        )
        .animation(.default)
    }
}
```

Note: You can of course still have an `onChanged` and `onEnded` block, you just don't have to set the offset to `.zero` any longer since it happens automatically.

### Update

If you are to use it inside `ObservableObject` class and want your dragOffset to be published, then [here would be a solution I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64735580).

Comment: I fear, there is still the issue that ScrollView cancels any drag gesture immediately when it starts its now no matter with which policy you add it. So, `updating` will be called once, then the gesture will be cancelled and never called again.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper My view is inside a scrollview, and it doesn't seem to pose any problem. I am wrapping my view inside a button, and the gesture seem to propagate just fine (a clumsy workaround, I know, but the updating method works just great in my ScrollView)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution to this problem is to add geometry reader in the background. On change of geo.frame(in: .global).minY (when scrolling) update the offset. This method uses a small amount of processing (I found a ~2% increase in CPU usage).

Add the following code somewhere in the view :

```
.background(Group{
    GeometryReader{ geo in
        HStack{
             
        }
        .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .global).minY) { _ in
            // update the offset
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think `scrollView` has its own gestures, such as `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer` in UIScrollView, to add a `DragGesture` on `scrollView` will confuse it.

you can change your code a little like:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .offset(x: dragOffset.width, y: dragOffset.height)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in self.dragOffset = value.translation }
                .onEnded { value in self.dragOffset = .zero }
        )
    }
    .animation(.default)
}
```

I think it can work well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Could you tell me why gesture can't be added to `Rectangle` instead of  `scrollView`? Maybe we can think of another solution

Comment: It can, but it changed nothing, I have a solution now, thank you!